# How to remove white space at the end of webpage - only appears in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, whitespace

I've been working on a website and I can't get rid of the white space that keeps adding itself at the end of the page. This only seems to happen with Chrome, all other major browsers don't have this problem.

The link to the website is : http://www.santullofitness.com/classes.html

I've checked other answers to the same problem, but none of them seem to fit my case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you !

Comment: where do you see whitespace?

Comment: I'm using chrome and I can't see said white space.

Comment: I agree with above comments.  This page looks fine in chrome on mac, I don't see any white space at the bottom of the page.  When does it add itself?

Comment: After the animation , the image is larger then the `body`. Try adding `height: 620px;` to `.animate-in`.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache - it's a long-shot but sometimes helps. I'm viewing on Chromium, and it's fine.

Comment: Not really.... I'm using latest version of Chrome and I see the white space. Check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked your web's CSS file. At least, the beggining.

Always remember to use a CSS Reset solution to normalize all styles cuz in different browsers renderization can be a lot different.

My recomendation: Erid Meyer's solution. Found here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Also, use this for your html and body (in the CSS file):

```
html, body {height: 100%; }
```

Best of luck!